# Parsing the name of multidimensionnal array

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

I'm using PHP to try to parse a string matching this kind of pattern :

```
field[foo][bar]
```

I use preg_match_all to get the indexes of the array ('foo' and 'bar' in this case). Here is my code, but it does not work :

```
preg_match_all("/\w+(\[(\w*)\])*/", $string, $matches);
```

And I'm getting these matches :

```
array

    (3) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=> string(15) "field[foo][bar]"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=> string(5) "[bar]"
      }
      [2]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=> string(3) "bar"
      }
    }
```

and I would like something like that :

```
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=> string(15) "field[foo][bar]"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=> string(5) "[foo]"
        [0]=> string(5) "[bar]"
      }
      [2]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=> string(3) "foo"
        [0]=> string(3) "bar"
      }
    }
```

(Actually, I'm only interested in the last array, the one without the square brackets)

I don't know why I'm getting only the last match...

Any idea ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a try with:

```
preg_match_all("/(\[(\w*)\])/", $string, $matches);
```